# Flutter Firebase using whereIn and WhereNotIn crashes Flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make a dating app and I need the query to not return a documentId which has already been gone through and an age range which documentID date of year needs to be. I tried the following ideas but both make the app crash is there any work around or something?

```
                fireStoreGlobal.collection('TestUsers')

                //1 using Range Operator on Single Field

                    .where('ID', whereNotIn: [
                // Local Variable List Sample
                      '9f8fe3c0-83fb-11ec-ba7d-71eedc0beebe',
                      '3eb69ae0-83fa-11ec-b4a4-cba7e6a8918b'
                    ])
                    .where('DOB', isGreaterThan: 2000, isLessThan: 2005)
                    .orderBy('ID', descending: true)
                    .orderBy('DOB', descending: true),


                //2 Using WhereIn

                .where('ID', whereNotIn: [
                  //Local Variable List Sample
                  '9f8fe3c0-83fb-11ec-ba7d-71eedc0beebe',
                  '3eb69ae0-83fa-11ec-b4a4-cba7e6a8918b'
                ])
                .orderBy('ID', descending: true)
                .where('DOB', whereIn: [2018, 2019, 2020])
                .orderBy('DOB', descending: true),
```

Error I get thrown is following

An error occurred while parsing query arguments, this is most likely an error with this SDK. (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000115fb9fba __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000115e63ff5 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   FirebaseFirestore                   0x000000010b79308b _ZN8firebase9firestore4util16ObjcThrowHandlerENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 683
3   FirebaseFirestore                   0x000000010b7923c5 _ZN8firebase9firestore4util5ThrowENS1_13ExceptionTypeEPKcS4_iRKNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS5_11char_traitsIcEENS5_9allocatorIcEEEE + 53
4   FirebaseFirestore                   0x000000010ba5540d *ZN8firebase9firestore4util20ThrowInvalidArgumentIJNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS3_11char_traitsIcEENS3_9allocatorIcEEEES9_EEEvPKcDpRKT* + 77
5   FirebaseFirestore                   0x000000010ba54b0a _ZNK8firebase9firestore3api5Query17ValidateNewFilterERKNS0_4core6FilterE + 890
6   FirebaseFirestore                   0x000000010ba53eae _ZNK8firebase9firestore3api5Query6FilterERKN
Lost connection to device.

Comment: whats the error you are getting when it crashes?

Comment: the error is more but there is a word limit on here

but I edited my question with error message

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing two incompatible queries. Taken from the [firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations): `In a compound query, range (<, <=, >, >=) and not equals (!=, not-in) comparisons must all filter on the same field.` You are trying to do a `not-in` query on `ID` and a range comparison `<` `>` on `DOB`. This is most likely the reason the app is crashing.

There are a couple other problems I see with this that you might want to fix.

1. Where in & where not in only support up to 10 values. So if you want to exclude more than 10 people in your query, it won't work. [firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#limitations_2)
2. You are trying to order by id's (a unique field) and then by DOB. Your second order by will have no effect. [firestore documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Comment: you know what im trying to do could you possibly structure a query that does what I want?

Comment: Not with firebase. Firebase has limited querying capabilities so that it can be fast and scalable. the only solution I can think of is to do a `where in` with your `DOB` field and then write some code to filter out the already seen users. If your app scales though, you'll end up paying a lot of money due to all the reads that causes.